# Web standard - why is it better to put <img> inside text or <div> with backround-image?

Tags: html, css, web, media-queries, standards

I am in need of changing  the image based on some media queries. Of course I cannot change `<img> href` in css but I am willing to make a workaround because it doesn't make sense to put `div` inside `<p>`.

What would be better?

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to handle image width size in media query, if you directly style over it. It doesn't matter whatever wrapper you are using for your image but always style for `(div#xyz or .xyz) > img`.

Comment: And also div with background image may not be easier to handle. You may use it when you are in the need of screen width size containers or in  bigger aspect, but image within text would be better choice for smaller aspect.